# IndexError: tuple index out of range - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

After some modifications, and changing `read()` to `browse()`, my method looks like this:

```
@api.multi
def update_url(self): 
    data = self.env['wizard.seniat.url'].browse()[0] 
    url_obj = self._get_url() # cr ,uid, ids, context
    url_obj.write(
        {'name': data and data['url1'],
         'url_seniat': data and data['url2'],
         'url_seniat2': data and data['url3']})
    return {}
```

Originally, on v8 it looked like this:

```
def update_url(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    data = self.pool.get('wizard.seniat.url').read(cr, uid, ids)[0]
    url_obj = self._get_url(cr, uid, ids, context)
    url_obj.write(
        {'name': data['url1'],
         'url_seniat': data['url2'],
         'url_seniat2': data['url3']})
    return {}
```

This is migration from v8 to v10, community

When I click on the button, It throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 74, in update_url
data = self.env['wizard.seniat.url'].browse()[0] 
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 5175, in __getitem__
return self._browse((self._ids[key],), self.env)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I still can't figure it out, any ideas?

Comment: We can not use *browse()* method without id/ids of recordset. We must give records ids to read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a list of IDs to use `browse`, as Jignesh Jarsaniya already stated in his answer. This module is really hard to understand and therefor difficult to migrate, by the way.

I would migrate this method like:

```py
@api.multi
def update_url(self):
    for url in self:
        url_obj = url._get_url()
        url_obj.write({
            'name': url.url1,
            'url_seniat': url.url2,
            'url_seniat2': url.url3
        })
    return {}
```

But it could be wrong, since i don't know what `_get_url` or what the return value looks like. But this method seems to be multi record usable, so why not make it multi record usable. If it is not needed or just shouldn't be allowed, migrate it like:

```py
@api.multi
def update_url(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    url_obj = self._get_url()
    url_obj.write({
        'name': self.url1,
        'url_seniat': self.url2,
        'url_seniat2': self.url3
    })
    return {}
```

Comment: Wow, Thank You very much, Indeed, this module has some "weird" features, and just as You said is kind of difficult sometimes to understand the underlying logic, to actually migrate it, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem in the **update_url()**. You should have to mention id to browse in the **browse()** but in your case you have the current record object in self.

```
@api.multi
def update_url(self): 
    # No need to browse because you have already current record in self 
    # data = self.env['wizard.seniat.url'].browse()[0]  
    url_obj = self._get_url() # cr ,uid, ids, context
    url_obj.write(
        {'name': self.url1 or False,
         'url_seniat': self.url2 and False,
         'url_seniat2': self.url3 and False})
    return {}
```

This may help you.